# Python tabula-py error (pandas error?)

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, tabula

After some reading online I have decided to use tabula-py to extract tables from pdf files. We use Anaconda and I just installed tabula-py 1.1.1.

I wanted to start out with a simple script and see what it would do with a single page pdf file with some text and two tables ("table_p16.pdf").

The code:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
df = read_pdf("table_p16.pdf")
```

The error:

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=c:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment\sam.security
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "H:/Personlich/SVN/blademat_tb/blademat_toolbox/utility/read_pdf.py", line 41, in 
>       df = read_pdf("table_p16.pdf")
>
> File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\tabula\wrapper.py", line 117, in read_pdf
>       return pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(output), **pandas_options)
>
> File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 709, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>
> File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 455, in _read
>       data = parser.read(nrows)
>
> File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1069, in read
>       ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
>
> File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxxxxxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\test_env\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1839, in read
>       data = self._reader.read(nrows)
>
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 902, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
>
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 924, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
>
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 978, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
>
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 965, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
>
> File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2208, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
>
> pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 9, saw 9

Things I have tried:

- Since the error seems to show problems with pandas I tried to read a
  single page pdf with one table. The same error holds.
- Set user variable PATH to Java. Did not change anything. Can't set
  system variable PATH to Java, since it is currently used for our SVN
  programm.
- Different code lines, with the same error:

  ```
  df = read_pdf(r"table_p9.pdf")
  df = read_pdf(r"table_p9.pdf")
  df = read_pdf("table_p9.pdf", output_format='json')
  ```

I hope someone can chip in and help me figure out where the problem lies. It could be a Java issue, but I am not that familiar with the required Java interaction. Your help is much appriciated.

**Edit**

I tried different tables and some seem to be working. It has been difficult to identify what type of tables work. Some with 'merged' columns and others with 'merged' rows seem to work. But clearly not all. Also, I have not been able to read multiple tables (2 or 3) using the argument multiple_tables=True.

Is there any source to what kind of tables Tabula can handle? And this makes me wonder whether Tabula is the right program to use. After all the reading I did, I was under the impression that Tabula would be good at this. The tables it seems to struggle with are not complex.

Is there a clear and simple source on how to maximize the use of Tabula? Or otherwise tips on how to deal with tables that Tabula struggles with?

Regards,
Gabriel

Comment: Please add the error you get as text, instead of as a link to an image. This makes it easier for search engines (if someone else encounters the same problem), people with screenreaders and also for people who don't click on random links on the internet.

Comment: From the error it sounds like your table does not have the same number of columns everywhere. This might be the case because of joined cells, or because of the parser splitting on the wrong tokens (single whitespace, with one cell containing a two words).

Answer (score 4):

This is the rough guideline for tabula (or tabula-py) options.

1) Having merged cells with a lined table
You can use `lattice=True` option. With lattice mode, tabula handles line of tables appropriately. Note that, you might need post editing some kind of fillna for merged cells. I experienced some merged columns is extracted with left-justified.

AFAIK, it's pretty hard for tabula to extract merged cell without line of table.

General tuning points for tabula are `lattice`, `stream`, `guess`.

2) Having multiple tables within one or more pages
It's tabula-py specific option, you have to use `multiple_tables=True` option.

By default, tabula-py tries to extract tables via CSV. While this approach can get benefits from pandas.read_csv function like inferring of column names. read_csv assumes a single table (same column size table) in a PDF. pandas.read_csv with different size of columns causes ParserError.

On the other hand, with `multiple_tables` option, tabula-py creates DataFrame via JSON, which can represent multiple tables.

One more option. From tabula-py 1.3.0, you can use Tabla app templates with tabula-py. Getting area data from template, you could extract more appropriately with accurate area info.