# Unable to read pdf with tabula

Tags: python-3.x, tabula

I'm getting into the below error while trying to read a pdf file with tabula(tabula-py).

Is there a way to read pdf in python like pandas or some other libs?

please suggest.

```
>>> from tabula import read_pdf
>>> df = read_pdf('OpTransactionHistory28-08-2018.pdf')
Aug 29, 2018 10:40:27 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider loadDiskCache
WARNING: New fonts found, font cache will be re-built
Aug 29, 2018 10:40:27 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider <init>
WARNING: Building on-disk font cache, this may take a while
Aug 29, 2018 10:40:32 AM org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.FileSystemFontProvider <init>
WARNING: Finished building on-disk font cache, found 328 fonts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/karn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tabula/wrapper.py", line 119, in read_pdf
    return pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(output), **pandas_options)
  File "/home/karn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/karn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 446, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/home/karn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1036, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/home/karn/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1848, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 876, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 891, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 945, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 932, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2112, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 4, saw 9
```

One way around i see is `pdftotext` conversion..

```
$ pdftotext OpTransactionHistory28-08-2018.pdf
```

Just looked upon the provide link by @ace and found something relevant:

```
>>> from tabula import read_pdf
>>> df = read_pdf('OpTransactionHistory28-08-2018.pdf', pages='all', encoding='ISO-8859-1', multiple_tables=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Python tabula-py error (pandas error?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51326900/3488231) but there was no answer there.

Comment: @ace  i looked upon that but as you said there is no answer to the question there.

Comment: Possibly related GitHub issues: [1](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/issues/12) [2](https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/issues/33)

Comment: @ace ,  there is few hints i see which may be useful, i'm looking on that

Comment: @ace, while using option as below it works somewhat...



`>>> df = read_pdf('OpTransactionHistory28-08-2018.pdf', pages='all', encoding='ISO-8859-1', multiple_tables=True)`

Comment: `url = 'https://archives.nseindia.com/technology/content/TP_CM_Trimmed_NNF_PROTOCOL_4.9.pdf'`

`tabula.read_pdf(url,stream=True,pages='186')`

And the output is

`>>> 
[   Error Code ID  Error  Description of  Error Code
0            NaN   Code                         NaN
1            NaN  Value                         NaN]`

Any idea why it is not able to read table, I have tried both encoding as well as multiple_tables options but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

The error of pandas layer often could be caused by the difference in column numbers between tables, since pandas try to extract one DataFrame from tabula-java output. Using `multiple_tables=True` can avoid this restriction since tabula-py aware boundary of tables.

I also noted this related error but seems different from what I saw.
https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py#i-faced-cparsererror-how-can-i-extract-multiple-tables

It would be much appreciated if you can provide your pandas version.

Comment: @ chezou .. thanks for your inputs, my panda version is `>>> pd.__version__
'0.21.0`

Comment: already used the `multiple_tables=True`  with  `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` and that worked.

Comment: @pygo Thanks for your info! I'll add the FAQ after investigation.

Comment: @ chezou .. thnx

Comment: did you get something on it or added some FAQ.